# Unable to launch application "javaws"

Tags: java, java-ws

I am unable to launch "**javaws -viewer**". I am on "**Windows10**" and when I type the below command in Run window, I get an error message. Please find the screenshot for the same below.

```
javaws –viewer
```

[javaws viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zyqge.png)

Clicking on **Details**, I see the following trace. Any help would be appreciated.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: –viewer (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.javaws@9.0.4/com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.javaws@9.0.4/com.sun.javaws.Main.prepareLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.plugin@9.0.4/sun.plugin2.main.WebStart.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.plugin@9.0.4/sun.plugin2.main.WebStart.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.plugin@9.0.4/sun.plugin2.main.WebStart.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.plugin@9.0.4/sun.plugin2.main.WebStart$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Additional Details:**

- I have two versions of Java installed on my windows machine (Java8 and Java9). In environment variables, I have set the **JAVA_HOME** to point to Java8 and the Path is also pointing to "**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin**" but somehow I see the Java-9 version in the command prompt result

(**Note:** Restarted command prompt multiple times after setting the environment variables. Not sure if the original issue is tied up with this one).

> ```
> >java -version
> java version "9.0.4"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The oracle installer puts a directory (C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath) with links to the installation in front of the path. Check your path variable and check whether you have multiple java executables on the path with "where java".

Comment: Yes in the path variable, I see that it is also pointing to "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath", so I have removed it now from the path variable. So it fixes the second issue which I have reported but the original issue still remains the same.

Comment: But the stacktrace changed, I guess? What is the current error message? You could also add -verbose to the command call to get more information.

Comment: Ok, so I am able to launch the "javaws" successfully now. From the command prompt, if I type "javaws -viewer" it is opening fine. But when tried the same command with Run windows, I get the same error message as earlier. Its not a big problem now but if you know the reason for it then please let me know. Thanks a lot for all the help.